# PowerShell script to copy files but not subfolders to SFTP and move to subfolder once done

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, get-childitem, winscp-net

I am using the following script to copy files from my local folder to SFTP. Once I upload the file I then want to move the file to a subfolder. I want to upload only files in the `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp` folder, and not files in the other subfolders.

```
param (
    $backupPath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp\moved"
)

# Load the Assembly and setup the session properties
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll" 

    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    $filelist = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp 

    # Connect And send files, then close session
    try
    {
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary

        foreach ($file in $filelist)
        {
            $transferResult = $session.PutFiles("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp\$file", "/", $False, $transferOptions)
            foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
            {
                Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
                Move-Item $transfer.FileName $backupPath
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }

    exit 0
}
# Catch any errors
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

At this moment, if I run the script all files under the **moved** folder will also get uploaded through SFTP folder, and I just need to upload the files in the root directory of the `ftp` folder.

I guess I will need to change this line here, but not sure on how to change it.

```
$filelist = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem -File  - only returns file objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the folders add `-File` switch to the `Get-ChildItem` *(as already commented by @Scepticalist)*:

```
$filelist = Get-ChildItem -File C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp
```

---

Though you can achieve the same with less code, if you let WinSCP iterate the files (and skip the folders):

```
$transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
$transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
$transferOptions.FileMask = "|*/" # Exclude the folders

$transferResult = $session.PutFiles(
    "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp\*", "/", $False, $transferOptions)
foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
{
    Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
    Move-Item $transfer.FileName $backupPath
}
```

And you do not need any `Get-ChildItem` call.

The above is basically the code from WinSCP article [Moving local files to different location after successful upload](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_local_move_after_successful_upload), just with an [exclusion of subfolders](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_script_non_recursive).

---

Though note that your code (contrary to the article) does not have a test for a successful upload. So you will move even files that fail to upload. Make sure you add the `$transfer.Error -eq $Null` test.

```
foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
{
    # Success or error?
    if ($transfer.Error -eq $Null)
    {
        Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded, moving to backup"
        # Upload succeeded, move source file to backup
        Move-Item $transfer.FileName $backupPath
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) failed: $($transfer.Error.Message)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
Get-Item C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ftp -include *.*
```

this should not get into subfolders.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately when I try this, it still gets into subfolders